# Get base href angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

My app has export to excel functionality, but i also would like add link field at export worksheet. It link should consists of baseUrl and some parameters ( e.g localhost:8080/params).

BaseUrl represent location [domain + [port]) from which was sent request to export

How can i get baseUrl in Angular4 component ( I believe it something related to routes, but i can't work out)

I have already tried use `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`, but it didn't solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current URL with this.router.url attribute.

You need to import Router:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

EDIT:
You can get parameter part easily:

```
     if(this.router.url.indexOf('/') >= 0){
         let parameterPart = this.router.url.substring(this.router.url.indexOf('/'));
     }
```

hope i help you!

Comment: it attibute returns params part ( e.g if i have 'localhost:8080/SomeParameter' then it will return '/SomeParameter part'). I would like return 'localhost:8080' part. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window object for getting the Base URL.

```
console.log(window.location);
```